# Where do things like prefix shorthand and shortcuts get documented in the Ruby API references?

Tags: ruby, hash, iterator, hashtable, block

Example:
In chapter two section five of Ruby Cookbook for random numbers there is this method. But it doesn't work.
What are they trying to do?

```
def random_word
  letters = { ?v => 'aeiou',
              ?c => 'bcdfghjklmnprstvwyz' }
  word = ''
  'cvcvcvc'.each_byte do |x|
    source = letters[x]
    word << source[rand(source.length)].chr
  end
  return word
end
```

Where in the Core API reference do these short-hands/shortcuts/prefixes or what have you get documented? I'm currently using version 2.3.0 but have the chm for 2.2.3

Comment: Thanks! I did look for this at first but was unable to find a similar question.

Answer (score 3):

Prior to Ruby 1.9, `?c` would return the ASCII code character for `c`, which is 99. In Ruby 1.9 and later, `?c` just returns a string. You can get the ASCII code character using `?c.ord` instead.

If you change the letters definition to

```
letters = { ?v.ord => 'aeiou',
            ?c.ord => 'bcdfghjklmnprstvwyz' }
```

the code should work again.

Comment: This works in pre-v.1.9 only because the method [Integer#ord](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Integer.html#method-i-ord) was provided. Would it not be better to write `'v'.ord` or `"v".ord`?

Comment: That's just the way the book is. It could be an older edition. I have July 2006: First Edition. All the code listings are on the O'Reilly site. http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596523695.do

Answer (score 2):

That cookbook must have been written for Ruby version 1.8. You could get a character's integer ordinal like so:

```
# 1.8
1.8.7 :001 > ?c
=> 99

# 1.9 and upwards
2.3.0 :002 > ?c
=> "c"
2.3.0 :002 > 'c'.ord
=> 99
```

You must have been using Ruby later then `1.8`. The following should work:

```
letters = { 'v'.ord => 'aeiou',
            'c'.ord => 'bcdfghjklmnprstvwyz' }
```

Comment: In part because of the version issue, I see no reason to *ever* write `?c`.

Comment: Yes it now works. Thanks!